# JavaScript arrow function create li objects and add to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, arrow-functions

This front-end JavaScript code works, it creates li itens in a ol tag from a list of string data. I would like to do it in just one line...

```
    qelements.map(element => { let litag = document.createElement("li");
                                litag.innerHTML = element;
                                oltag.appendChild(litag) });
```

But this one I get an error: "qlist.html:32 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

```
qelements.map(element => oltag.appendChild(document.createElement("li").innerHTML = element));
```

Taking out the ".innerHTML = element" it creates empty li elements inside a ol tag as expected

Comment: You shouldn't use `map` if you're not interested in the return value; use `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
document.createElement("li").innerHTML = element
```

is an assignment expression. Its resulting value is going to be whatever is on the right hand side of that equals sign (which I'm assuming is a string).

So when you do this:

```
qelements.map(element => oltag.appendChild(document.createElement("li").innerHTML = element));
```

You are essentially passing `element` to `appendChild` and abandoning the newly created `li` element, which isn't what you want to do.

If you want to avoid having multiple lines in that particular part of your code, you can factor out a function for creating the `li`:

```
function makeLi(content) {
    let litag = document.createElement("li");
    litag.innerHTML = content;
    return litag:
}
```

Then use it:

```
qelements.forEach(element => oltag.appendChild(makeLi(element)));
```

Note also that you seem to be abusing the `map()` method. If you just want to iterate over a series of values and do something with each one, use `.forEach` or `for .. of`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Valuable hints! :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion:

- You should use `snake_case` or `CamelCase` for naming your variables. (`qelements` -> `qElements` or `q_elements`
- You should write simple, easy to understand code, not combining complex codes. If you are in a team and you do this, you will kill every one else, they will have a hard time understand what you are writing. Even if you come back and read these codes after a long time, you will not understand yourself.

In this case you can create a helper function to make it one line:

```
const createLiTagWithText = text => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = text;
  return li;
}

qElements.map(element => oltag.appendChild(createLiTagWithText(element)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oltag.appendChild(document.createElement("li").innerHTML = element)
```

This passes the return value of the assignment expression to `appendChild`, in other words, it's the same as `oltag.appendChild(element)`. The first version is already pretty much the most readable way to do it.